# Ember push record in model and update template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this route in my Ember app:

```
model: function(params, transition) {
    var self = this;

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        photo: self.store.find('photo', params.id),
        comments: self.store.query('comment', {id: params.id})
    });
},

actions: {
    newComment: function(comment) {
        var record = this.store.createRecord('comment', comment);

    }
}
```

The template:

```
{{#each model.comments as |comment|}}
    <div class="card">
        <div data-userId="{{comment.userId}}">
            <b>{{comment.username}}</b>
        </div>
        <div>
            {{comment.content}}
        </div>
        <span class="hide-on-small-only">{{i18n 'createdAt_lbl'}}: </span>{{format comment.createdAt type='date'}}
    </div>
{{/each}}

{{post-comment newComment='newComment' comments=model.comments}}
```

and the comment model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    commentHash: DS.attr('string'),
    content: DS.attr('string'),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    userHash: DS.attr('string'),
    userId: DS.attr('number'),
});
```

The post-comment component is the one responsible to call the newComment action:

```
// post-comment component
var self = this;

// get the new comment content from textarea
var $contentArea = this.$('#postCommentContent');
var content = $contentArea.val();

var newComment = {
    userId: localStorage.getItem('userId'),
    content: content,
    createdAt: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
};
self.sendAction('newComment', newComment);
```

What I need is to be able to add a new local comment (without persisting it on the server) dinamically and make the template update to show the newly added record without a complete page refresh

Comment: please post a snippet of your template as well so its easier to help you

Comment: please also post your `comment` model that you have defined

Comment: @mihai I've updated the question with the requested informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a modifiable copy of the list of comments and keep it on the controller:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(...arguments);
  controller.set('comments', model.comments.toArray());
}
```

The reason you need to make a copy is that the return value from `store.query` is, for various reasons, unwritable. There may be other ways to make a copy but `toArray` seems to work well.

Add the new comment to this list after creating it:

```
actions: {
  newComment: function(comment) {
    var record = this.store.createRecord('comment', comment);
    this.get('comments').pushObject(record);
  }
}
```

In your template, loop over the controller property:

```
{#each comments as |comment|}}
```

Comment: ok thans for pointing out that the query result is unwritable; in any case "this.get('comments').pushObject(record) does not work; I've changed it to "this.get('controller').get('comments').pushObject(record) that correctly updates the array but the template does not update after that

Comment: Well, I did not know where the actions were defined. I assumed it was on the controller. It's an anti-pattern to manipulate the controller from the router. Therefore, I would move the action to the controller. I'm not quite sure if that would solve the problem of the template not updating though. Are you sure you fixed the template to loop over `comments` instead of `model.comments`?

Comment: yes I've changed the template's loop; but aren't controller's deprecated in ember 2.x? In any case to make the template updating to show the new comment is my main purpose

Comment: No, they're not deprecated whatsoever. They're an indispensable element of any Ember app. There's a vision or statement of direction for "routable components" which might land in Ember 2.12 or who knows when, at which point they **will** be. Deprecation has a very specific meaning in Ember-land. It means a feature has a replacement available NOW which you should switch to and if you don't you will see a deprecation message.

Comment: Ok, in any case I've tried with the action on controller but seems that it does not cause the template to update

Comment: That's mysterious. Can you confirm that you have changed the loop in the template to loop over `comments` instead of `model.comments`?

Answer (score 0):

It should simply work like this:

```
newComment: function(comment) {
    var record = this.store.createRecord('comment', comment);
    var commentsModel =  this.get('model.comments'); // or this.get('comments'), depending where you action resides
    commentsModel.pushObject(record);
    this.set('model.comments', commentsModel); // or this.set('comments'), depending where you action resides 
}
```

This only works if you actually have comments. If not, you first need to initialize your comments as an empty array. Otherwise:

```
newComment: function(comment) {
    var record = this.store.createRecord('comment', comment);
    var commentsModel =  this.get('model.comments'); // or this.get('comments'), depending where you action resides
    if(!commentsModel){
        commentsModel = Ember.A();
    }
    commentsModel.pushObject(record);
    this.set('model.comments', commentsModel); // or this.set('comments'), depending where you action resides 
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunally no; doing this I get the error "pushObject of undefined"

Comment: Updated the answer. I didn't know on which scope you are calling the acton

Comment: Also if the comments are not empty, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function" when trying to push the new record in the model

Comment: Don't understand the last line in the first fragment. Why would I need to reset `model.comments` to the same value it already had? Also, comments should never be null; `query` will return an empty array if there are none.